# CosmosDB emulator can't start since port is already in use

Tags: windows, azure-cosmosdb

I'm giving CosmosDB a chance and so I decided to build an app that uses it, but I'm running into this issue when using the emulator: Port is already in use.

I'm not sure where to reconfigure the port the emulator is pointing.

[image]

Comment: I get this error constantly even though nothing is using port 8081.  Not sure what is going on...

Answer (score 11):

If you prefer just to change the Windows Shortcut, right click > properties and add  `/port=8082` (or whatever port number you want) at the end of the `Target` field after the quotes.

Note that in the Emulator Data Explorer, the URI field still showed the default port of 8081.

[image: Shortcut properties]

Answer (score 9):

You can use /Port option to configure the emulator to listen to a different port.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#a-idcommand-lineacommand-line-tool-reference

Comment: Thanks for the reference. This worked. Also worked to simply restart my computer. The ports got reassigned automatically to different ones.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem, where i got an error "port 10253 already in use" which is a port for Direct connectivity. Direct connectivity port defaults for CosmosDB are 10251,10252,10253,10254.

Used the following Command-line Syntax to change the default port and it worked,

> **CosmosDB.Emulator.exe** /DirectPorts=10261,10262,10263,10264

---

OR (in my case)

---

> **"C:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\CosmosDB.Emulator.exe"** /DirectPorts=10261,10262,10263,10264

**Note: You can use port of your choice, but make sure that they are not already in use**

Answer (score 4):

The CosmosDbEmulator comes with a PowerShell module, which you can use to control it.

To get started using the module run the following command:

```
 Import-Module "$env:ProgramFiles\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\PSModules\Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Emulator"
```

Start the CosmosDbEmulator on a port of your choice, e.g 8082 as follows:

```
Start-CosmosDbEmulator -port 8082
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your processes list and find one like `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.GatewayService.exe`. Kill it. Then I can start Cosmos emulator.

Comment: This is the way. Don't work around problems. Fix them.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working with powershell.

Import module

```
$env:PSModulesPath += "$env:ProgramFiles\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\PSModules"
Import-Module Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Emulator
```

Stop CosmosDB emulator

```
Stop-CosmosDbEmulator
```

Start CosmosDB emulator with prefered port

```
Start-CosmosDbEmulator  -Port 10101
```

And I got it working... Hope this helps.

Comment: For me the first import module command had to be a bit different:
`$env:PSModulePath += ";$env:ProgramFiles\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\PSModules"`

Answer (score 1):

With the latest (2.14.3) that I installed today, you need to specify /mongoport instead of /port.

[image]