# Windows: Include port number in shortcut target string

Tags: windows, exe, azure-cosmosdb, shortcut

For Azure Cosmos DB Emulator, you have to specify a port number with the exe.  For me and a few others, port 8080 is already in use so you have to use so you have to use ports: 10261,10262,10263,10264
([CosmosDB emulator can't start since port is already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851311/cosmosdb-emulator-cant-start-since-port-is-already-in-use)) and (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#command-line)

My question is, is there a way to add "/port=10261" to the shortcut target that references the exe?

The current target exe is: "C:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe"

[image]

I would like for the target exe to be this: "C:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe/port=10261"

However, I get this error:
[image]

It does work in the command prompt, but I was looking to see if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"-port=10261" works.  It doesn't like slashes.

Here is the full shortcut target string that works: "C:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe" -port=10261

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use slashes if you enclose them in quotes, like:

"C:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\CosmosDB.Emulator.exe" "/port=10261"